# How to create nested scroll view fields in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, nested-forms

How can I create Nested Fields like [this](http://crystalsoft-sy.com/agenda.html) in IOS. Later I will create a .plist from this fields.

I guess Scrollview inside of another scrollview  is best solution for this ? If so how can I keep track ids of Input Fields?

Comment: have u thought about tableView..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [image]
- ID Tracking: I didn't get you here. If you use NSCore Data isn't NSManagedContextObject is sufficient to handle all of this (or do I miss something here)!
- MANN